Vuforia AR video background texture accessing problem in Unity Engine
I am working on a Vuforia AR application in Unity Engine. The Unity version is 2022.3.31f1, Vuforia SDK version is 10.24.4 and the project is running on the IOS platform.
I am having an issue accessing the background video texture using API:
VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.VideoBackground.VideoBackgroundTexture.
The API returns a "Texture" value. I debugged the returned texture value is not null even also applied the texture value onto a "Raw Image" component to visualize the graphics of the returned texture for debug purposes but there are no graphics in any pixel channel. It seems like a fully transparent image, not a black image.
I also tried to call the start and stop video background rendering method by the listed APIs below:

VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.VideoBackground.StartVideoBackgroundRendering()
VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.VideoBackground.StartVideoBackgroundRendering()


There are two main ways to access and use the camera images rendered on the Video Background: accessing the VideoBackgroundTexture to render the images with a different material or on a different object, and retrieving the Image from the CameraDevice to access the pixel data and save it or manipulate it as you prefer.
In the first case, if you want to render the VideoBackground on a different object, you can assign the VideoBackgroundTexture to the mainTexture of the object's material.
For example, you can do so by using this code in a MonoBehaviour class and adding that MonoBehaviour to the object you want to use for rendering:
void Awake()
{
    VuforiaApplication.Instance.OnVuforiaStarted += VuforiaStarted;
}

void VuforiaStarted()
{
    VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.VideoBackground.OnVideoBackgroundChanged += OnVideoBackgrounChanged;
}

void OnVideoBackgrounChanged()
{
    var videoBackgroundTexture = VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.VideoBackground.VideoBackgroundTexture;
    var meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshRenderer.material.mainTexture = videoBackgroundTexture;
}

Note: remember to always unsubscribe from all the events during OnDestroy.
In the second case, if you want to access the Image from the CameraDevice, you can try to use this code sample from the Vuforia documentation. The page can also give you some more insights into how Vuforia uses the images from the camera feed and how to work with the camera.
